# How to label charts when using multiple matplotlib figures?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to know how can I label multiple matplotlib charts, please?

If I call `.xlabel()`, or `.ylabel()` on plt directly only one of the graphs gets labelled, however if I call the functions on the figure, I get an error.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(19680801)
N_points = 100000
dist1 = rng.standard_normal(N_points)

fig1 = plt.figure()
axis = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
axis.grid()

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax = fig2.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.grid()

plt.xlabel('X AXIS')
plt.ylabel('Y AXIS')
axis.hist(dist1)

ax.hist(dist1)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the labels using the `Axes` (`axis` and `ax` in you case) with the `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel` methods. E.g.,

```py
# add labels onto the first plot
axis.set_xlabel("X AXIS")
axis.set_ylabel("X AXIS")

...

ax.set_xlabel("Another X AXIS")
ax.set_ylabel("Another X AXIS")
```

Note that you're currently also creating two separate figures. If you want two plots on the same figure you could do:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
```

Then `ax[0]` will be the first axis onto which you can plot and `ax[1]` will be the second.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to call .xlabel() directly on the axes, but that resulted in an error. I didn't realize that I have to use a different method. Thanks for the reply.